# Recibo el valor dentro de la clave

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, express, fetch

Enviando un formulario por FETCH de un estado de REACT a nodeJS, recibo en el servidor el objeto pero dentro de la clave del objeto recibo tambien el valor, adjuto caps y code

El fetch del cliente

```
            fetch("http://localhost:9000/user/",{
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(varinputs),
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                }
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

lo que recibe el servidor

```
POST /user - - ms - -
{
  '{"name":"Guillermo ","email":"gggpaantin@gmail.com","password":"adssadsa"}': ''
}
```

Testando con Postman mi servidor y con el mismo header sí se envía normal, varinputs es un estado de React donde cobra forma de objeto

19/11/21

Al final, al estar usando distintos puertos 3000 en React y 9000 en el servidor, al enviar dicha información el servido no identificaba bien la cabecera, esto se pudo solventar usando una liberia llamada "CORS"

Arquitectura del servidor

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

// Settings, configuración del servidor
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 9000);

// Middlewares

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Routes

app.use(require('./routes/index.routes'))

// Errors
app.use((err, req, res, next)=>{
    res.send({ error:  err.message });
});

// Public

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../log-in/public')))

app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=>{
    console.log(`Server on port ${app.get("port")}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un middleware que haga esto. Por fortuna, express ya viene preparado con ambos.

#### express 4.0

```
app.use(express.json()); // Para formato json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Puedes ver [más info aquí](https://expressjs.com/es/api.html#express.urlencoded).

Comment: ya pude solventar al estar usando  distintos puertos  puerto 3000 para el  React y 9000 para el servidor, algo le ocurría a la cabecera, no sé que exactamente, investigando me encontré una librería que solventaba eso. La instalé y en efecto, llega la información de manera correcta. El nombre de la librería es "cors"

Comment: Por si te interesa más del tema [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Sí porfavor, leí un poco de ella pero no es que capté del todo